# Word Riddle : I am a 10 letter word

Tags: riddle

[Riddle :](https://brainyyou.com/2018/06/03/english-word-riddle-i-am-a-10-letter-word-who-am-i/)

I am a 10 letter word.

1,2 = A preposition

10,7,6 = Needed for living

5,3,7 = It's a grain.

4,1,9,6 = The process of becoming less bright.

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is

> [asafoetida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asafoetida)

Each line

> refers to taking the nth letters. For instance:
>  1,2 = A preposition  = AS
>  10,7,6 = Needed for living  = ATE (a little iffy, but I suppose "needed" could be past tense)
>  5,3,7 = It's a grain. = OAT
>  4,1,9,6 = The process of becoming less bright. = FADE